# Add blog posts without category in django 1.11

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to add some blog posts with categories and some without categories in django. with this models django admin won't let me add blog posts without a category. Thanks.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink


class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    # Many-to-one relationship. 
    category = models.ForeignKey('blog.Category')


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your model like this:

```
category = models.ForeignKey('blog.Category', blank=True, null=True)
```

`blank=True` allow forms to have a blank value. 
`null=True` allows a null value in the database.

Edit: here is the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#null)